# What is the syntax in an Oracle regexp_replace statement to ignore a tag and everything inside it?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need help with a regular expression replace in Oracle. I want to replace all occurrences of a word or phrase that exists in a document, as long as the word or phrase does not exist within a set of tags. The tags are defined by me (hot html or xml) and my current concept is;

```
<term type=pos id=123>some phrase</term>
```

I have created a function wrapper (non-functional) for the regexp_replace that looks like this;

```
  FUNCTION ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM(IN_TEXT IN VARCHAR2, SEARCH_TERM IN VARCHAR2, TERM_TYPE IN VARCHAR2, RECORD_ID IN NUMBER) RETURN CLOB
  IS
    REGEX_SEARCH VARCHAR2(512);
    REGEX_REPLACE VARCHAR2(512);
  BEGIN
    REGEX_SEARCH := '((<TERM.*?</TERM>|[^<])*?)(^|\W)('|| SEARCH_TERM ||')($|\W)';
    REGEX_REPLACE := '\1 <TERM ID='|| TO_CHAR(RECORD_ID)||' TYPE=' || TERM_TYPE ||'>'|| SEARCH_TERM ||'</TERM> ';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REGEX_SEARCH = ' || REGEX_SEARCH);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REGEX_REPLACE = ' || REGEX_REPLACE);
    RETURN TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(IN_TEXT, REGEX_SEARCH, REGEX_REPLACE,1,0,'in'));
  END ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM;
```

When called like this;

```
SELECT ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM(
                         ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM('dog elephant dog cat cat dog dogfish fishdog mouse dog', 'DOG CAT', 'POS', 123),
                         'DOG', 'POS',456) 
FROM DUAL;
```

It returns;

```
<TERM ID=456 TYPE=POS>DOG</TERM> elephant <TERM ID=123 TYPE=POS>DOG CAT</TERM> cat <TERM ID=456 TYPE=POS>DOG</TERM> dogfish fishdog mouse <TERM ID=456 TYPE=POS>DOG</TERM>
```

Which is correct. But if called with this;

```
SELECT ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM(
                         ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM('elephant dog cat cat dogfish fishdog mouse', 'DOG CAT', 'POS', 123),
                         'DOG', 'POS',456) 
FROM DUAL;
```

It returns;

```
elephant <TERM ID=123 TYPE=POS <TERM ID=456 TYPE=POS>DOG</TERM> CAT</TERM> cat dogfish fishdog mouse
```

Which is wrong. It appears to be eating a ">" and finding the word/phrase within the tags.

I am actively trying to increase my knowledge about regular expressions, but this one has eluded me thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you tried to match "negatively", I tried a direct match just using the closing markup `<\TERM>` and that seems to work:

```
create or replace FUNCTION ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM(IN_TEXT      IN VARCHAR2,
                                             SEARCH_TERM  IN VARCHAR2,
                                             TERM_TYPE    IN VARCHAR2,
                                             RECORD_ID    IN NUMBER)
RETURN CLOB IS
    REGEX_SEARCH  VARCHAR2(512);
    REGEX_REPLACE VARCHAR2(512);
BEGIN
    REGEX_SEARCH := '(?</TERM>| |^)' || SEARCH_TERM || '( |$)';
    REGEX_REPLACE := '\1<TERM ID=' || TO_CHAR(RECORD_ID) || ' TYPE=' 
                     || TERM_TYPE || '>' || SEARCH_TERM || '</TERM>\2';

    RETURN TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(IN_TEXT, REGEX_SEARCH, REGEX_REPLACE,1,0,'in'));
END ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM;
```

We then obtain:

```
SELECT ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM(
           ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM('dog elephant dog cat cat dog dogfish fishdog mouse dog',
                             'DOG CAT', 'POS', 123),
           'DOG', 'POS',456) 
FROM DUAL;
```

gives :

```
<TERM ID=456 TYPE=POS>DOG</TERM> elephant <TERM ID=123 TYPE=POS>DOG CAT</TERM> cat <TERM ID=456 TYPE=POS>DOG</TERM> dogfish fishdog mouse <TERM ID=456 TYPE=POS>DOG</TERM>
```

and

```
SELECT ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM(
          ANNOTATE_ONE_TERM('elephant dog cat cat dogfish fishdog mouse',
                            'DOG CAT', 'POS', 123),
          'DOG', 'POS',456) 
FROM DUAL;
```

gives:

```
elephant <TERM ID=123 TYPE=POS>DOG CAT</TERM> cat dogfish fishdog mouse
```

as expected, no cross terms. You have to use tricks like this because Oracle doesn't support lookahead/lookbehind assertions (at least in my version, 11g).

Comment: Since knowledge is power, can you explain in a little more detail the concepts in the expression you used?

Comment: Sure ! Basically, it says: search for a term, with either a space/the beginning of the line/a closing markup before (capturing group #1), and either a space/the end of the line after (capturing group #2). Then replace it by the term formatted into markups, with captured groups around. Using the closing markup as significant before forbids opening markups to be detected.